# Using a gradient mesh to color lines in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, gradient-mesh

So I have this line design in AI, and I made this super colorful gradient mesh with the color design I want to apply to the lines. (They are in separate layers if that is relevant) How do I use the color design of the gradient mesh to color the lines?

Answer (score 1):

If the line design isn't too complex, one way of solving this problem is to create a **clipping mask**:

- convert the strokes of the object to outlines,
- merge the resulting objects together using pathfinder tools,
- create a clipping mask with the line design on top of the gradient mesh.

This works in Illustrator CS5 and i can't say if newer versions allow to do it in a different way.